# How to find an .exe file path using node js

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm running electron and nodejs on Windows 10

How can I find a path to an executable?

one way would be to run a cli command that will use something like

```
where myfile.exe
```

is there a node-ish way?

Comment: Please illustrate your scenario and why the path is not known to you. Are you looking for a function that searches in a directory or the entire file system?

Comment: how do yo u wants to find it? please add more details to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [which module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which):

```
 var which = require('which')

// async usage
which('node', function (er, resolvedPath) {
  // er is returned if no "node" is found on the PATH
  // if it is found, then the absolute path to the exec is returned
}).
```